# PickAdate not working with autoform materialize

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, materialize

i get the below error when trying to use PickAdate with gildaspk:autoform-materialize version :0.0.7 [image: bug]
here's my schema field :

```
 when: {
    type: Date,
    autoform: {
      type: 'pickadate'
    }
```

here's my form declaration :

```
{{#autoForm id="addEvents" collection="Events" type="insert"}}
  {{> afFieldInput name='when' type="pickadate"}}
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Comment: Could you please run `meteor list` and add the version number of `gildaspk:autoform-materialize` to your question?

Comment: done! now i worked it around by instanciating the pickadate manualy on template render.

Comment: You should update the `gildaspk:autoform-materialize` package to the latest version or at least to version [`0.0.11`](https://github.com/djhi/meteor-autoform-materialize/issues/7).